# Get string from array in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have this array called **commitInfoAll** in my Jenkins pipeline, 
I'm trying to get only the commit hashes from this array into another list/array.
the number of commits can be 1,2,3...n.

```
commitInfoAll: 
  [Commit: acaf95bf73804bb3a3c10b0352c2d566506c26f5
  Author: Shachar
  E-mail: Shachar@google.com
  Date: Oct 30, 2019 11:38:43 AM GMT+02:00
  Message: Getting commit info (schedulertCommitInfo) #2


  , Commit: a1720a49e7f0ed98c25a4119ae961b71d7e3fdc3
  Author: Shachar
  E-mail: Shachar@google.com
  Date: Oct 30, 2019 11:38:24 AM GMT+02:00
  Message: Getting commit info (schedulertCommitInfo)
 ]
```

What I want to get in the end is an array like this :

```
[acaf95bf73804bb3a3c10b0352c2d566506c26f5,a1720a49e7f0ed98c25a4119ae961b71d7e3fdc3,...and so on]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer

```
List hashes = commitInfoAll*.commitId
```

Long answer

```
List hashes = commitInfoAll.collect{ it.commitId }
```

Comment: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field com.github.jenkins.lastchanges.model.CommitInfo Commit

Comment: you provided an example with `Commit` field present. Based on https://github.com/jenkinsci/last-changes-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jenkins/lastchanges/model/CommitInfo.java you should replace it with `commitId`